# I want to retrieve state id based on selected country in tableview

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview, nsdictionary

My database like this.

Country table

```
{"country_id":"88","country_name":"India","country_code":"in","continent_code":"AS"}
```

State table

```
{"state_id":"1379","country_id":"88","state_name":"Sikkim","state_html_name":"Sikkim"}
```

I wrote this code.

```
for(NSDictionary *cid in wholeJsonArray)
    {

        NSNumber *number = [cid objectForKey:@"country_id"];
        [idcountry addObject:number];

    }
```

I get proper country ID.
But when i wrote this for state id based on selected country its could display 0 objects.

```
for(NSDictionary *cid in statearray)
    {

        NSNumber *statenumber = [cid objectForKey:@"state_id"];
        [idstate addObject:statenumber];

      }
```

This code in tableview `didSelectRowAtIndexPath`

```
NSString *statename=[stateArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        stateid=[idstate objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        [stateButton setTitle:statename forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

Answer (score 0):

Problem is on this **Line :**

```
[idstate addObject:number];
```

You should add `statenumber` instead of `number`. **Like this :**

```
[idstate addObject:statenumber];
```